# Problem with numbering in Markdown

Tags: support, markdown

When using a numbered list that's interrupted by a quote for each item, it's being rendered correctly in the edit/preview screen, but ends up 'resetting' each item in the final version.

**In edit mode:**

[image]

**The actual post:**
[image]

I read Jeff's answer on Daniel Beck's question stating that the preview is like a view-finder, but I'm not sure if this qualifies as a similar problem.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you're formatting correctly.

1. Item one

   ```
   code one
   ```
2. Item two

   ```
   code two
   ```
3. Item three

   ```
   code three
   ```

Make sure all the code is idented eight (8) spaces.

Beyond that, it is true that Markdown will renumber lists for you, e.g.

1. one
2. one
3. one

is actually submitted as

```
1. one
1. one
1. one
```

But I don't think that's what you're asking about -- I think you have an error in your formatting.

Comment: taken, the help does state it clearly. allthough there is a diff in what the preview renderer creates and what the final renderer does, thats why i didnt read the help ("what could possibly go wrong, preview looks great").

Answer (score 2):

I've actually had this same issue as well... As a work around until this is fixed I just add a second period to the number....

> 1..
>
> 2..
>
> 3..

This forces the markdown to treat it other than a list.  You won't get indented formatting that normally comes with numbering but will at least make the numbers correct.

Comment: aah ... chicken :)